# How Do I fix a "[Error 30] Read-only file system" when trying to install?

Tags: installation, read-only

Please, I would like to know how to fix this problem in order to install Ubuntu 11.04 again.

```
[Error 30] Read-only file system:'/target/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic'
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If Linux detects a problem on the harddrive, it will switch the filesystem to read only to prevent damage to the filesystem.

Since this is happening during install, I would assume something is wrong with the CD (ie. a bad ISO). You can find this out by running the 'check cd' option you get during boot. If this shows errors you need to re-download and re-burn the install disc.

If the installation disc turns out to be perfect it is likely to be a hardware problem. It could be your hard disc that is failing. Or if it is a desktop it could also be a faulty cable.